# Write out Mixed GAM model mathematically

Tags: regression, mixed-model, generalized-linear-model, binomial-distribution, generalized-additive-model

How do I write out the following mixed Generalised Additive model?

```
library(mgcv)
gam(Secondary_yes ~ s(Year, sp=0.1) + LocSub +  s(Region, bs = "re") + s(Primary, bs = "re") + s(Primary, Year, bs = "re"), data = df_spec3 , family = binomial, method = "REML")
```

Summary:

```
Parametric coefficients:
                  Estimate Std. Error z value Pr(>|z|)    
(Intercept)        -2.3093     0.5913  -3.906  9.4e-05 ***
LocSubSubstantive   0.8663     0.3070   2.822  0.00477 ** 
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Approximate significance of smooth terms:
                  edf Ref.df   Chi.sq  p-value    
s(Year)         3.192   3.98    3.687   0.4493    
s(Region)       8.048  13.00   41.251 9.63e-05 ***
s(Primary)      7.102   8.00 1182.578 1.87e-07 ***
s(Primary,Year) 4.883   8.00  570.232   0.0411 *
```

This is my attempt based on reading the book by Wood (2011) on GAMS:

$Y_{ij} \sim Binom \left( n_{i}, p_{ij} \right) = {n_{i} \choose y_{i}} p_{ij}^{y_{i}}(1-p_{ij})^{n_{i}-y_{i}}$

$log \left( \dfrac{p_{ij}}{1-p_{ij}} \right) = \textbf{A}_{ij} \gamma + \Sigma_{j} f_{j}(x_{ji})$

where $A_{i}$ is the ith row of the paametric model matrix, with corresponding parameters $\gamma, f_{j}$ is a smooth function of vector covariate $x_{j}$.

Note: I have defined a mixed logistic regression as follows and am looking to produce something along these sort of lines

$Y_{ij} \sim Binom \left( n_{i}, p_{ij} \right) = {n_{i} \choose y_{i}} p_{ij}^{y_{i}}(1-p_{ij})^{n_{i}-y_{i}}$

$log \left( \dfrac{p_{ij}}{1-p_{ij}} \right) = X^{T} \beta + Z b$

$b = \left( b_{1},...,b_{g} \right) \sim MVN(0, \Sigma_{b})$

where
X = N $\times$ q = 1141 $\times$ 3 design matrix
$\beta$ = q $\times$ 1 = 3 $\times$ 1 regression vector
Z = N $\times$ r = 1141 $\times$ 1 design matrix
b = r $\times$ 1 = 1 $\times$ 1 vector of random effects
$\Sigma_{b}$ = covariance matrix, which simplifies to $\Sigma_{b} = \tau^{2} 1_{g}$ if the random effects are i.i.d

Thank you for any help!

Comment: It looks like you've answered your own question.

Comment: I believe I may be close but I am not confident, I am not sure if the subscripts are correct for the context of a mixed model.

Comment: You haven't explained what your subscripts are but all of the random and fixed effects details are subsumed in the model matrices and coefficient vectors.